# What's a popular programming technique to handle a failure in a Multi-Step, Multi-Tier process?

Tags: javascript, database, e-commerce, structure

I'm working on a simple e-commerce site. When a user makes a purchase, it triggers a couple of synchronous, cascading events. Some data is written to our database, the purchase is OK'd (or not) by the Credit Card vendor, some more data is to our database, then an email is sent.

```
Step 1. Initial Purchase info recorded on local database
Step 2. Purchase API called on Credit Card vendor
Step 3. Details of transaction written to local database
Step 4. Email receipt/alert sent
```

Is there a proven methodology to handle when one of these steps fails? For instance, if we've already written to our database, but then the credit card transaction fails. Or we've made it through steps 1 and 2 but step 3 fails. I'm trying to understand the basics- like is it more prudent to create a 'pre-purchase- snapshot of the data, then roll everything back if something fails, or create a 'fake purchase' object and assuming everything goes OK, then copy that into the actual database.

Any suggestions are welcome. I am way out of my league on this one.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest that the database information is atomically correct at the time of insert. this goes pretty directly with proper normalization.

so for example, if the customer enters his address, then that gets saved to the db - it is still valid even if the customer fails to make an order.

similarly, if the customer places an order - that is valid, even if the credit card transaction fails - which would be a separate fact somewhere else.  (this fact would be checked before say the shipping step was allowed)

the email step would maybe change its message depending on the facts available, but you would not want to roll back a purchase if the email server was down for instance.

so my suggestion: normalize well, and keep all info as it occurs, then check appropriately during key steps in the process. - do not roll back.

Comment: Many thanks Randy. I'm going to Google some tonight and learn what proper normalization is. Cheers!